# SQL - filter table from another table

Tags: sql

I have two table.

```
EX_A:
Select TAB1,TAB2,max(TAB3),TAB4,TAB5,TAB6
FROM TEST
where TAB1 = 'BLACK' or TAB1 = 'RED' or TAB1 = 'YELLOW'
group by TAB1,TAB2,TAB4,TAB5,TAB6
-----------------------------------------------------
EX_B:
select TAB2A, max(TAB2B)
from TEST2
where TAB2A = 'BLACK' or TAB2A = 'RED' or TAB2A = 'YELLOW'
group by TAB2A
```

This table is also select from other tables.

But in order to provide data, so I use CREATE TABLE here.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
TAB1 VARCHAR(50),
TAB2 VARCHAR(50),
TAB3 VARCHAR(50),
TAB4 VARCHAR(50),
TAB5 VARCHAR(50),
TAB6 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES ('BLACK', '2.4', '20201019', '20000', '102','UA'),
('BLACK', '2.4', '20201019', '10000', '102','UA'),
('BLACK', '1.8', '20201019', '50000', '103','UD'),
('BLACK', '1.8', '20201019', '25000', '103','UD'),
('RED', '9.6', '20201015', '1000', '102','UA'),
('RED', '5.2', '20201020', '5000', '104','UD'),
('RED', '5.2', '20201020', '1000', '104','UD'),
('YELLOW', '7.5', '20201012', '5000', '102','UA');
---------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE TEST2 (
TAB2A VARCHAR(50),
TAB2B VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO TEST2
VALUES ('BLACK', '20201019'),
('RED', '20201020'),
('YELLOW', '20201012');
```

Like this

[image]

I hope to find the largest TAB3 based on TAB1 and output this result.

[image]

I try to use EX_B as Subquery to filter out EX_A.

I keep getting errors and I don’t know where is the problem.

```
Select TAB1,TAB2,max(TAB3),TAB4,TAB5,TAB6
FROM TEST T1
where T1.TAB1 IN
(select TAB2A, max(TAB2B)
from TEST2 T2
where (TAB2A = 'BLACK' or TAB2A = 'RED' or TAB2A = 'YELLOW') and T2.TAB2A = T1.TAB1
group by TAB2A)
group by TAB1,TAB2,TAB4,TAB5,TAB6;
```

What should I do to complete my task

Thank you

Comment: `||` is concatenation in SQL. And you can't concatenate boolean expressions... Use AND/OR instead.

Comment: Thank you, I modified the content

Comment: Still getting errors?

Comment: `where T1.TAB1 IN
(select TAB2A, max(TAB2B) ...` will not work. One item is compared to two items.

Comment: Yes, I found this problem, but I don’t know what else I can use

Comment: "I keep getting error"  What's the error???

Answer (score 0):

This gives the output you have shown, (as per [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e201093830765c925a1ab72fc1a6aa0a)), but I'm not sure your data set demonstrates your problem sufficiently. According to what you've provided, you are doing an equijoin on the values in table TEST2 column, so I'm not clear where the need for MAX comes in. So if this answer is not correct, please update your question to provide additional data that demonstrates the issue.

```
SELECT a.* FROM test a
JOIN test2 b ON a.tab1 = b.tab2a and a.tab3 = b.tab2b
```

EDIT: If you want dates (I presume they're dates!) in table TEST (tab3) that are **equal or greater than** the dates (tab2b) in table TEST2, then just change `a.tab3 = b.tab2b` to `a.tab3 >= b.tab2b`